# sqlpackage exception: Unrecognized command line argument BlockOnPossibleDataLoss

Tags: cmd, sqlpackage

I'm running the below command in my `CMD`:

```
sqlpackage /action:Publish /SourceFile:"Database Services\bin\Release\Database Services.dacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=TEST05,123;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Initial catalog=test" /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False
```

but getting this exception:

```
*** Unrecognized command line argument 'p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False'.
```

What is wrong with the syntax? I followed the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15#properties-specific-to-the-publish-action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution :) I had to run the `CMD` as administrator